# Difference between class references in Kotlin

Tags: types, reference, kotlin

I found that there are (at least) two ways to reference a class in kotlin:

```
var tempRecipe: RecipeTemplate? = null
```

and

```
var tempRecipe2 = RecipeTemplate::class
```

What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var tempRecipe: RecipeTemplate? = null` Here you are creating a variable which will store the reference of an instance of RecipeTemplate which can be null.

`var tempRecipe2 = RecipeTemplate::class` Here you are creating a variable which have value of `type KClass`.

The above two is same campare to java first one is like creating a varibale to store an instance like `RecipeTemplate tempRecipe = RecipeTemplate()`
and the second one is like `Class tempRecipe2 = RecipeTemplate.class`.

Comment: Gottcha! Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: It is different from Class in way that it is reimplemented in kotlin own way. But the motivation of both are same.

Comment: I updated type at fist place from Class to Kclass and at second place i am writing it comparing to java so there it will be Class. thanks @Enzokie

Answer (score 0):

`var tempRecipe: RecipeTemplate? = null`
means that `tempRecipe` references to an object which is a `RecipeTemplate`

`var tempRecipe2 = RecipeTemplate::class`
means that `tempRecipe2` is a reference to an object which is a `KClass`

Because the reference isn't the same:

On `tempRecipe` you can call all methods which `RecipeTemplate` has. On `tempRecipe2` you can't. But you can call the method `cast` for example, because `KClasses` has this method.